# Facebook Graph API 2 permission to allow "Stories shared with you: check-ins, photos, status updates and videos"

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I trying to write an app to retrieve status updates of my friends on facebook. There are other apps available to do that but I have a concern that its maybe not possible with Graph API 2. That being said as facebook is all about the status updates I would be surprised if that is true.

Looking at other apps that can do what I want to too I think the permission I need is one that results in:

This app needs:
Stories shared with you: check-ins, photos, status updates and videos

Now, I have used the Graph API Explorer and selected all permissions when I generated the token and still when I look in Apps on the main site even the graph explorer doesn't have this permission text.

From what I can see/read it's possible that this feature has been removed and the intention is that now you have to invite all of your friends to share their status with this app too?

Hopefully someone out there knows the permission or can categorically state that it is no longer possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With v2.0 of the Graph API, all friends permission have been removed. See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_permissions

Comment: Thanks for the response, so is it really the case that now it is impossible to access friends status updates without them choosing to share directly with my app?I am not really sure what the API is for then, I was hoping to integrate into Facebook but it seems more like it allows you to access facebook as a contact facilitator but nothing more.

Comment: I share your concerns as well. Graph API v2.0 kind of sucks to be honest. I always wonder why there's no huge outcry among the app developer community...