# iOS facebook sdk getting private posts of all my friends

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

i'm new to iPhone programming and Facebook sdk. I would like to collect everything that my friends post (all statuses, changes, profile updates etc) and show it in my app. Is that possible?

So far, i found a way to collect only 25 latest public posts by the following code:

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:
    @[
        @"public_profile,
        user_friends",
        @"read_stream"
    ]
    allowLoginUI:YES
    completionHandler: 
        ^(FBSession *session,
        FBSessionState state,
        NSError *error) { ... }
];

FBRequest *request = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"me/home"];
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: It probably comes in pages. Look into pagination.

Comment: You're just reading your own stream, not the ones of your friends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Graph API v2.0, all friends permissions have been removed, meaning that you no longer can access the friend's data programatically.

See [Facebook Graph API 2 permission to allow "Stories shared with you: check-ins, photos, status updates and videos"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24180010/facebook-graph-api-2-permission-to-allow-stories-shared-with-you-check-ins-ph/24181350#24181350)

Comment: Meaning in fb graph api 2 is absolutely not possible to gather posts, except public ones?